# Private key recovering from both addresses + signed transaction?

Tags: transactions, myetherwallet, private-key, encryption

Hello I have a problem.

I have two computers, one of them is airgapped

I have downloaded and runned Myetherwallet locally on an airgapped computer.

On the other computer I made the on line transaction

But here comes the problem:

I have written both the addresses to wich to send the coins from and to on the pc connected to internet

You know that when you run MEW LOCALLY you have to write an on line form and an offline form and then put the signed transaction into the on line form

The problem is that a potencial attacker could have those things recorded on my internet computer:

1) the address which I am sending the coins FROM

2) the address which I am sending the coins TO

3) the signed transaction made from that two addresses.

With all those informations is it possible to recover the Private key whith some kind of tools?
comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The only way they could get your private key is if they got your private key. It can't be reconstructed from signed transactions or addresses.

Comment: Are you sure?  Even if  I have used  another address?  I will explain:  After  I have  sent  the tokens  to this  address,  I have made another transaction using  one address  previously used + another address (a new one)  using another private key (on the airgapped computer). But  the  combo   new address + signed transaction + previous address +  old signed  transaction  are  still on my internet PC...  I would like to know if there is  a remote  way to exploit  some kind of pattern , comparing the two signed transactions  with the  3  addresses   used  to recover  the one key..

Comment: Basically I have  2 private keys.  Once  I made  a  transaction using the first private key to send  the coins to the second  private key's address  and  the combo (addresess  +signed transaction  was recorded  on the internet PC). Then I made a  second  transaction  from the  second   private  key's address  to  another ethereum address, completly new. In this case  was  also recorded  on my internet PC  the combo (second  private key's address +  new signed transaction +  new address  to send  the coins TO). Well   with all those information can  an attackker  build a pattern for decryption?

Comment: No. Again, the signed transaction is signed *by* your private key. it doesn't not contain your private key, nor can it be "unsigned" in order to derive your private key. ***If*** it were possible to obtain a private key from a signature, all cryptography (not just your Ethereum account) would be hopelessly broken and everything would be insecure and someone would remotely press the button that control all the nukes in the world and we would die.